# How to recognize object from image?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, vision

I have photos of robots. I want a program that can split the image into tiles (I don't need help for this) and find out in which tiles the robots are. Thus, I need the program to analyze a tile and find out whether it contains a robot. How can I do this? [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joRXT.jpg), [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oujdj.jpg)

I do not know how many robots there are in the image in advance. I know that this is a complicated problem and I do not expect a full solution, but some pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Object recognition and detection constitutes an entire field of computer vision. There are literally thousands of papers on this topic. The accuracy and complexity of an answer depends heavily on how constrained your task is. You need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: As I wrote, there will be an image of an area populated with some robots. The area will be thought of as a grid. Think of a chessboard with its squares. The problem is to determine which squares contain a robot and which do not. I have pictures of such areas which I could use for training, i.e., telling the program that in these photos, this square has a robot and that one does not, but I don't know how to go from training to the actual task.

Comment: share those photos... do you have any idea how many kinds of robots there are?  what is "some robots" says nothing. how does the floor look like? from what perspective do you take your images, what are the lighting conditions?  that's like asking a doctor to recommend the best surgery because you don't feel well...

Comment: @Piglet done. Ideally, I would like a solution that is independent of the type of floor, perspective, etc., but if that is not possible then a solution dependent on those things. As I wrote in my edit, I do not expect to receive a full solution here, but some pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: so you want to detect an unknown number of robots reliably on a quick and dirty cellphone snapshot on any kind of floor? is there any reason why you can't take proper pictures?

Comment: Piglet for your first sentence, basically yes, although it doesn't have to be on a cell phone. What do you mean by proper pictures?

Comment: Or if you have an answer that only applies for a particular type of floor, such as a white floor like in my images, please give that.